# Understanding dropwizard metrics

Tags: multithreading, profiling, dropwizard

I'm doing some performance tests on my app and at some point the app stops responding. Checking the thread's log at http://localhost:7771/threads, I've found the following data:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.dw.utilization" : {
  "value" : 1.0
},
```

Does that mean that my application is overloaded?

Also there are some interesting numbers about the threads:

```
"jvm.threads.blocked.count" : {
  "value" : 0
},
"jvm.threads.count" : {
  "value" : 152
},
"jvm.threads.daemon.count" : {
  "value" : 12
},
"jvm.threads.deadlock.count" : {
  "value" : 0
},
"jvm.threads.deadlocks" : {
  "value" : [ ]
},
"jvm.threads.new.count" : {
  "value" : 0.
},
"jvm.threads.runnable.count" : {
  "value" : 11
},
"jvm.threads.terminated.count" : {
  "value" : 0
},
"jvm.threads.timed_waiting.count" : {
  "value" : 9
},
"jvm.threads.waiting.count" : {
  "value" : 132
}
```

The number of waiting threads are almost the same as the number of total threads.

So which "metric" should I use to determine if there are something blocking the threads?

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean interface is responsible for collecting all metrics for threads and it is only interface for managing all java threads in JVM.

Dropwizard is just a wrapper on it, and its ThreadStatesGaugeSet class provides a way to  return counts of threads in different states using API exposed by ThreadMXBean.

Since in your case, jvm.threads.blocked.count is 0, so there is no thread blocked, however,  you have high value of jvm.threads.waiting.count metrics, which is as per java doc is caused mainly due to Object.wait, Thread.join or locksupport.park methods. Below is link for JAVA API documentation, which can provide detail insight on it. Also some of JVM threads like finalize, Reference Handler etc. will be also be in waiting state. So, above waiting count is application + JVM threads.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

In above scenario, we can see that there are 11 runnable threads, which means try to look into your OS configuration as well and how much OS resource these running thread are taking. Are they long running threads or not? If it is not long running, then next metrics should reflect it (By default in Dropwizard it is emitted after every 1 min, but can be configured to have any value based on application need). Analysis of thread dump will also be helpful.